# Kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

One often says that the kernel of a linear functional has codimension 1. Okay, consider $\delta_1\colon C[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\delta_1(f)=f(1)$. Then for each monomial $f_n(t)=t^n$ we have $\delta_1(f_n)=1$ and $\{f_n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ are linearly independent... What am I confusing here?

Comment: $f_n = f_m + (f_n - f_m)$. The difference $f_n - f_m$ is in $\ker \delta_1$.

Comment: But $f_n$ is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the kernel: $\forall n,\,\forall m\, f_m-f_n\in \text{Ker}\, \delta_1$.

Comment: but $\ker \delta_1 = \{f\colon \delta_1(f)=0\}$?

Comment: @oswald Of course. We write $\delta_1(f_m-f_n)=1^m-1^n=0$, hence $f_m-f_n \in\text{Ker}\,\delta_1$